# list keep this value the highest among 2

Tags: python

Hello I have a list which contains the name, first name and result. I would like to create a new list without duplicates.In this case 'M' exists twice so I want to keep only his best score.

I wrote this code but it keeps me duplicates.

I want that in output :

```
[['L', 'l', '7.69'], ['M', 'm', '9.10'], ['N', 'n', '7.69'], ['O', 'o', '5.90']]
```

Can you help me? Thank you.

```py
list_no_ok = [['L', 'l', '7.69'], ['M', 'm', '4.10'], ['M', 'm', '9.10'], ['N', 'n', '7.69'], ['O', 'o', '5.90']]
list_ok = []

for i, next_i in zip(list_no_ok, list_no_ok[1::]):

    if i[0] == next_i[0] and i[1] == next_i[1]:
        if i[6] > next_i[6]:
            lala = [i[0], i[1], i[2], i[6]]
        else:
            lala = [next_i[0], next_i[1], next_i[2], next_i[6]]
    else:
        lala = [i[0], i[1], i[2], i[6]]

    list_ok.append(lala)

print(list_ok)
```

Comment: What is your `desired output`?

Comment: It sounds like he's looking to generate a list of unique items based on the `but it doesn't work! because it keeps duplicates.`, but as @EL-AJIOussama said showing your `desired output` will make it easier to help.

Comment: I want to create a new list without duplicates. In this case 'M' exists twice so I want to keep only his best score.

Comment: @bendour Please edit your question to show the actual output that you want to get in this example.

Answer (score 0):

Very naive, not at all clever approach using a hash follows. Iterate over the list. For each list in the list, the first element is the key. Compare to the third value in the list already associated with that key. Of course, if we haven't looked at that key yet, an exception will be thrown. We can handle that by adding the current list to the hash with the current key.

We can get the list we want by using `values` and converting that to a `list`.

```
>>> a = [['L', 'l', '7.69'], ['M', 'm', '4.10'], ['M', 'm', '9.10'], ['N', 'n', '7.69'], ['O', 'o', '5.90']]
>>> h = {}
>>> for x in a:
...     key = x[0]
...     try:
...          if h[key][2] < x[2]:
...              h[key] = x
...     except KeyError:
...          h[key] = x
...
>>> h
{'L': ['L', 'l', '7.69'], 'M': ['M', 'm', '9.10'], 'N': ['N', 'n', '7.69'], 'O': ['O', 'o', '5.90']}
>>> list(h.values())
[['L', 'l', '7.69'], ['M', 'm', '9.10'], ['N', 'n', '7.69'], ['O', 'o', '5.90']]
```

Comment: I suggest that you catch the specific exception (`KeyError`) rather than a bare `except:`

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you use a dictionary in order to keep track of which row has the best score for each person, then loop through the rows, updating the dictionary unless a better score has already been seen for that person.

The key for the dictionary is a two-element tuple of the name and the first name.

Finally, output the values contained in the dictionary.

```
list_ok = [['L', 'l', '7.69'],
           ['M', 'm', '9.10'],
           ['M', 'm', '9.10'],
           ['N', 'n', '7.69'],
           ['O', 'o', '5.90']]

bests = {}

def score_from_row(row):
    return float(row[2])

for row in list_ok:

    key = (row[0], row[1])
    score = score_from_row(row)

    if key in bests:
        previous_best = bests[key]
        if score_from_row(previous_best) > score:
            continue

    bests[key] = row

print(list(bests.values()))
```

This gives:

```
[['L', 'l', '7.69'], ['M', 'm', '9.10'], ['N', 'n', '7.69'], ['O', 'o', '5.90']]
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming all the elements are 'finished', here is the code

```
def deDupe():
    list_ok = [['L', 'l', 'Finished', '7.69'], ['M', 'm', 'Finished', '9.10'], ['M', 'm', 'Finished', '9.10'],
               ['N', 'n', 'Finished', '7.69'], ['O', 'o', 'Finished', '5.90']]
    capture_dict = {}
    for element in list_ok:
        keyValue = '{0}{1}'.format(element[0], element[1])
        if keyValue in list(capture_dict.keys()):
            compare_value = capture_dict[keyValue]
            if float(element[3]) > float(compare_value[3]):
                capture_dict.pop(keyValue)
                capture_dict[keyValue] = element
        else:
            capture_dict[keyValue] = element
    list_2 = list(capture_dict.values())
    print(list_2)
```

Output:

```
>>> deDupe()
[['L', 'l', 'Finished', '7.69'], ['M', 'm', 'Finished', '9.10'], ['N', 'n', 'Finished', '7.69'], ['O', 'o', 'Finished', '5.90']]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an approach that parses your list and stores values as it goes in a `dictionary` and checks the current result against the highest result seen to date.

Why a Python `dictionary`? Because dictionaries:

- store key and value pairs (which is ideal since you want to correlate a name & a result)
- make it fairly simple to deduplicate values which is one of the goals (i.e. store only one result for `'M', 'm'`)

Let's look at the code:

```
list_no_ok = [['L', 'l', '7.69'],
              ['M', 'm', '4.10'], 
              ['M', 'm', '9.10'], 
              ['N', 'n', '7.69'], 
              ['O', 'o', '5.90']]
highest_values = {}

for name, first_name, result in list_no_ok:
    
    # To properly check the result values, convert to a float.
    result = float(result)

    # This step looks in the dictionary to see if a key that matches
    #     the name, first_name tuple exists and if yes, will get the 
    #     stored result so we can check to see if the next result is 
    #     higher. IF that tuple doesn't exist, it will return a default
    #     value of 0 (you can set that default to be number you want).
    
    current_value = highest_values.get((name, first_name), 0)
    
    # Here we check for the highest value and if the current result
    #     is higher than the stored value, then we replace it with the
    #     new higher value
    # If we have never seen the name before, the current value will be 0 
    # and the new result will be higher than that, so the
    # new result will replace the 0. Similarly if we we saw 
    # a lower value before, the new result will overwrite any previous lower values.
    
    if result > current_value:
        highest_values[(name, first_name)] = result
```

Lastly, once we have gone through all the values, we can then safely generate the final list for printing:

```
list_ok = []
for names, result in highest_values.items():
    # names will be the tuple we used as a key in the
    # dictionary, so it will need to be "unpacked" into
    # the separate values of name and first_name

    name, first_name = names
    list_ok.append([name, first_name, result])

print(list_ok)

[['L', 'l', 7.69], ['M', 'm', 9.1], ['N', 'n', 7.69], ['O', 'o', 5.9]]
```